# как узнать размер шрифта в пикселях для css из photoshop макета?

Tags: css, photoshop

Есть макет, если мерять линейкой в фотошопе высоту букв то получается 55px, но если я прописываю это значение в font-size, то буквы явно меньше чем в макете. Как определить замерами в фотошоп точное значение font-size?

Comment: Если текст нарисован, то скорее всего никак, только на глаз подбирать

Answer (score 0):

Если используете отладку через Хром, попробуйте расширение "PerfectPixel by WellDoneCode". Насчёт других браузеров не знаю

Answer (score 0):

В фотошопе есть функция текст ('T'), активируете её, после нажимаете на текст, если всё верно сделано, то у вас покажется семейство шрифтов и его размер.